# How to notify more than one View models when checkbox is unchecked or on an event? C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

There are  checkbox's in MainWindow (and MainWindowVM) on check of it other windows(But not all) should be notified, Current we are doing by handling events. that is each VM will subscribe to an event and whenever changes happen we will handle it in all VM's is there any better way of doing it?

Comment: I would suggest to use [Event Aggregator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx)

Comment: Do you work with custom events or with PropertyChanged?

Comment: @Rekshino custom events.

Comment: Is this an option: VM.PropertyChanged += ?

Answer (score 1):

> is there any better way of doing it?

Use an [event aggregator](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/) or a [messenger](http://dotnetpattern.com/mvvm-light-messenger).

This removes the tight coupling between the publishers and the subscribers. The subscriber of an event observes the event aggregator instead of the publisher and the publisher knows only about the event aggregator and not about the different subscribers.

This leads to code that is a lot easier to maintain. Please refer to the links for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use, what you already have, so subscribe for PropertyChanged of VM for MainWindow:

```
public class NonMainWindowVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public NonMainWindowVM(MainWindowVM mwVM)
    {
        mwVM.PropertyChanged += MW_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void MW_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case nameof(MainWindowVM.ID):
                //logic MainWindowVM.ID changed
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```