# Use selectedItem of treeview from another ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am a newbie in MVVM/WPF and try to use MVVM design pattern. I don't know how to describe my issue but let assume I have 2 ViewModel like below picture

[image]

RedViewModel has a treeview. When user click to treeview, it get selectedItem and send to BlueViewModel. Base on selectedItem from RedViewModel, BlueViewModel show data of selectedItem in textbox.

I don't know how to access and use variables between 2 MVVM.

Comment: You can use EventHandler that trigger when you select an item From RedViewModel.

Comment: can you give me more detail example :((

Comment: _RedViewModel has a treeview._ That is not MVVM, your are breaking MVVM. ViewModels should know nothing about Views

Comment: No, I am not mean like that, let image I am usimh Josh Smith's FamilyTreeviewModel, when I lick on each person, it's show another view which has person's detail information (Name, email, phone number, address...)

Comment: A window is not a view model...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:** The red and blue views could share the same view model. They could then simply bind to the same properties.

**Option 2:** If you want to stick with separate view model classes, you could send a loosely coupled message from `RedViewModel` to `BlueViewModel` when an item is selected using an [event aggregator or a messenger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48624857/7252182).

[How do I notify a parent view of a child view event in an MVVM WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43482545/how-do-i-notify-a-parent-view-of-a-child-view-event-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/43497967#43497967)

**Option 3:** Use a [shared service](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/22907a0f-d805-4195-8272-7c284b72d2ee/example-of-using-shared-services-prism?forum=wpf) in both view models.

Comment: Many thanks mm8, option 2 seem to be can fix my problem. It's also a new things to learn when working with wpf/mvvm

Comment: I just only have 1 more concern. which option is the best fit in my this situation. Can you suggest me the which one?

Answer (score 0):

You can't bind to the `SelectedItem` of a standard WPF `TreeView`. However, you can create a bindable property using a `Beahvior` class

```
public class perTreeViewHelper : Behavior<TreeView>
{
    public object BoundSelectedItem
    {
        get => GetValue(BoundSelectedItemProperty);
        set => SetValue(BoundSelectedItemProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundSelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BoundSelectedItem",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(perTreeViewHelper),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                OnBoundSelectedItemChanged));

    private static void OnBoundSelectedItemChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.NewValue is perTreeViewItemViewModelBase item)
        {
            item.IsSelected = true;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged += OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.SelectedItemChanged -= OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void OnTreeViewSelectedItemChanged(object obj, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> args)
    {
        BoundSelectedItem = args.NewValue;
    }
}
```

That way, you can bind to a property on one ViewModel that you can reference from the other. Obviously the two ViewModels need to be linked in some way - usually by having one as a property of the other.

More on my take on TreeViews in a WPF / MVVM context on my [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-behaviors-part-2-treeview/).

Comment: it's seem to be its not actually what i want to ask. The Josh Smith's familytreeview has own selectedItem. I can use it but just use in FamilyTreeViewModel scope. Let image if I want to double click to treeviewItem and its show another view that i can display name, email, phone number, address... How can I achieve it